# Jquery show hide not working with jquery waterwheel plugin

Tags: jquery

I am Using 7 image jquery waterwheel.

```
<div class="carousel-images">

            <img src="img/large_girl.jpg" title="Danielle M., 23Yrs., Model." id="oneimg" />
            <img src="img/large_girl.jpg" title="Selena Gomez., 20Yrs., Student." id="twoimg"  />
            <img src="img/large_girl.jpg" title="Alicia, 19Yrs., Model."  id="threeimg" />
            <img src="img/large_girl.jpg" title="Alicia, 19Yrs., Model."  id="fourimg" />
            <img src="img/large_girl.jpg" title="Alicia, 19Yrs., Model."  id="fiveimg" />
            <img src="img/large_girl.jpg" title="Alicia, 19Yrs., Model."  id="siximg" />
            <img src="img/large_girl.jpg" title="Alicia, 19Yrs., Model."  id="sevenimg" />
      </div>
```

i want to show the text of particular image clicked ie when image id "oneimg" is clicked then in below UL li the li with "one " should be visible.

```
<ul>          


<li id="one">
<img src="img/left_quote.png">You Wish You Could Dance With Me.  <span>I AM GAME</span> <img src="img/right_quote.png">
</li>

<li id="two">
<img src="img/left_quote.png">You Wish You Could Go To Beach With Me.  <span>I AM GAME</span> <img src="img/right_quote.png">
</li>

<li id="three">
<img src="img/left_quote.png">You Wish You Were Younger.  <span>GIVE ME A CHANCE</span> <img src="img/right_quote.png">
</li>
 <li id="four"><img src="img/left_quote.png">You Wish You Could Learn Portuguese.  <span>I AM GAME</span> <img src="img/right_quote.png">
</li>
<li id="five">
<img src="img/left_quote.png">You Wish You Could Get Closer.  <span>I AM GAME</span> <img src="img/right_quote.png">
</li>
<li id="six">
<img src="img/left_quote.png">You Want Me At Business Luncheon.     <span>I AM GAME</span> <img src="img/right_quote.png">
</li>
<li id="seven"><img src="img/left_quote.png">You Wish To Meet My Friends.  <span>I AM GAME</span> <img src="img/right_quote.png">
</li>
  </ul>
```

i am using this in jquery

```
$('.sevensins ul li').hide();

                    $('#oneimg').click(function(e) {
                        $('.sevensins ul li#one').show();
                        !$('.sevensins ul li#one').hide();
                        });                     

                    $('#twoimg').click(function(e) {
                        $('.sevensins ul li#two').show();
                        !$('.sevensins ul li#two').hide();
                        }); 

                        $('#threeimg').click(function(e) {
                        $('.sevensins ul li#three').show();
                        !$('.sevensins ul li#three').hide();
                        }); 

                        $('#fourimg').click(function(e) {
                        $('.sevensins ul li#four').show();
                        !$('.sevensins ul li#four').hide();
                        }); 

                        $('#fiveimg').click(function(e) {
                        $('.sevensins ul li#five').show();
                        !$('.sevensins ul li#five').hide();
                        }); 

                        $('#siximg').click(function(e) {
                        $('.sevensins ul li#six').show();
                        !$('.sevensins ul li#six').hide();
                        }); 

                        $('#sevenimg').click(function(e) {
                        $('.sevensins ul li#seven').show();
                        !$('.sevensins ul li#seven').hide();
                        });
```

Comment: How about remove duplicated code ?

Comment: actually what i want is the img with active class should show particular text in separate div... 7 images have seven different text....

Comment: solved by using .not() 
'$('.sevensins ul li').not('#five').hide("slow");'

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change all your javascript to the following.

```
$('.carousel-images img').click(function() {
    var id = this.id;
    id = id.substr(0, id.indexOf('img'));
    $('ul li:not(#' + id + ')').hide();
    $('#' + id).show();
});
```

Comment: Hello Ricardo I used the same and it works as it shows the particular text but after clicking two or more images. there should not be 3- four text shown means One text at one time on one click image... ????

Comment: :).. hey Ricardo i am basic learner in Jquery can you please teach me the Jquery or help me in becoming a master like you ???? Pleaseeeee.....

Comment: @Designerashish Sure, if you take a look the following link, which can be found on `jQuery` tag, you will see many interesting documents which can be very helpful. http://stackoverflow.com/tags/jquery/info